# Parse string to decimal and sum in sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion

I've been trying to add two values (which are strings) from a database query. I'm trying to parse them and add them in a database query but I can't.

**DB Values:**

```
Amount1:       -400 (string)
Amount2:        400 (string)
```

I need `(-400)+(400)` to be `0`.

**My code is like:**

```
var Result = Model.Fin.Where(*some conditions*).Sum(a => decimal.TryParse(a.Amount));
```

Can you help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TryParse` requires an `out` parameter along with the value to be parsed, also its returns value is `bool` not the decimal.

So the valid syntax you should be using is

```
var models = Model.Fin.Where(some conditions).ToList();
var Result = models.Sum(a => decimal.Parse(a.Amount))
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 0):

In case of `TryParse` you have to put *longer* and *inefficient* code:

```
var Result = Model.Fin
  .Where(*some conditions*)
  .AsEnumerable() // you'll need this as well (Linq to Sql doesn't support the next sum)
  .Sum(a => {
     decimal v;

     if (!decimal.TryParse(a.Amount, out v)) 
       return 0.0M; // a.Amount can't be decimal, say, "bla-bla-bla"

     return v;
   }
```

Since Linq to Sql can´t create a query with `decimal.TryParse` you have to switch to `Linq to Objects` - `AsEnumerable()` *fetch* the data and sum up it on the *client side*.